# Mobile version background image

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, background-image, image-scaling

So I have a website I am retooling.  Essentially I have 6 different containers.... 3 of the containers are set at a height of 700px.  I also have the following CSS:

```
.img2,
.img3,
.img4 {
   height: 700px;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

The desktop view looks flawless.  In the mobile version the background image is acting in a way I can't figure out.  It is just zoomed in, which I could understand why if it is taking the size of the image cause it is way too big to fit on mobile view... I resized the images and still zoomed in just even less clear... I have a webkit on the media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 812px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

to handle any funky browser stuff going on.  I am curious as to why when I resized the images to a smaller height and width and re-set the background in the media query it just got worse?  I am trying to just have the image (these images are big roughly 1200 x 1400) fill the div correctly as it does on desktop view.  My mobile view is being determined from my phone which is an iPhone.

Comment: Side note, fixed background normally doesn't work on mobile browsers.

Comment: It seems as though that fixed attribute was causing it to freak out.  I set it to scroll and the images look great, but obviously having to sacrifice the cool scrolling I have on desktop with fixed.  May have to try to settle with a parallax or something on mobile but we shall see.  Thank you guys for your input.